# apt-get: Unable to locate package bum

Tags: boot, apt

My computer boots very slow and I think I've got the problem. This is what dmesg says:

```
...
[   13.812524] Bluetooth: hci0 command 0x2010 tx timeout
[   97.224904] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
...`
```

It looks like the bluetooth is responsible for it. As I don't know how to repair it and I don't need bluetooth at all, I decided to tell Ubuntu not to load it. So I've been looking for a tool to do that. Everyone talks about "bum" but I can't install it. I looked for another choice, "rcconf", but I can't find it neither.

```
riqui@riqui-u:~$ sudo apt-get install bum
[sudo] password for riqui: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package bum
```

Do you know what am I doing wrong?

Comment: I can't even find the package here: https://packages.ubuntu.com/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are running Ubuntu zesty `bum` is not available to you, however if you are using Ubuntu xenial, vivid, trusty or precise you can install it using `apt-get`, first make sure your sources are up to date:

```
sudo apt update
```

then try installing it:

```
sudo apt install bum
```

*Remember some of versions which I mentioned are outdated like: vivid and precise.*

Comment: I am running zesty. Thanks. I'll look for another solution.